# Django bower, bootstrap, staticfiles doesn't work

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bower

i have problem with loading static files from django template.

Here is my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (                                                                                  
 33     'django.contrib.admin',                                                                         
 34     'django.contrib.auth',                                                                          
 35     'django.contrib.contenttypes',                                                                  
 36     'django.contrib.sessions',                                                                      
 37     'django.contrib.messages',                                                                      
 38     'django.contrib.staticfiles',                                                                   
 39     'chat',                                                                                         
 40     'ws4redis',                                                                                     
 41     'djangobower',                                                                                  
 42 )                                                                                                                                                                                                
 44 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (                                                                              
 45     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',                                         
 46     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',                                                    
 47     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',                                                    
 48     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',                                      
 49     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',                               
 50     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',                                         
 51     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',                                       
 52 )                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 54 ROOT_URLCONF = 'chrum.urls'                                                                         

 68 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')                                                      

 70 STATICFILES_FINDERS  = ("django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",                      
 71                         'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',                  
 72                         'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',)                                         
 73 STATICFILES_DIRS = (                                                                                
 74     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "components"),                                                           
 75 )                                                                                                
 77 BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')                                            
 78 BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = ('bootstrap',)
```

heres my template:

```
 4 {% load staticfiles %}                                                                              
  5 {% load static from staticfiles %}                                                                  
  6 <script src="{% static 'components/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js' %}"></script>                                                                                                
  7 <script src="{% static 'components/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>   
  8 <script rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  src="{% static 'components/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' %}"></script>
```

In site source, i can see that link works, and i can read my css file.

Server returns:

[05/Dec/2014 21:45:52] "GET /static/components/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Dec/2014 21:45:52] "GET /static/components/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Dec/2014 21:45:52] "GET /static/components/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0

but that css doesnt work, and i can't see it in style editor in my browser.

ps: if i import that css file in my browser manually it works!

Comment: What does your web browser (i.e. Chrome debugger) say that the resource path for the static files is?  Start there, and most likely it's just pointing to the wrong path.

Comment: In mozzila there is nothing. In chromium there are imported files in sources tab, but it doesnt work too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't defined `STATIC_URL` variable in your settings.py file. Add the following lines your settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this:

```
<script src="{% static 'jquery/dist/jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

Remove the `components/bower_components/` prefix.